# Fastest safe way to clean a Bugzilla installation?

Tags: bugzilla

I have a Bugzilla installation and I would like to clean the bugs, projects, components etc from it to start clean. But I would like to keep the users and other settings. How would I best do this so I don't fragment the installation?

Comment: What version of Bugzilla are you using?

Comment: I have two running versions. One is 3.6 and the other is 4.0. It's primarily the 4.0 one I would like to 'nuke'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way, for me, was simply to delete all the tables in the database. Most of the settings are kept in other places. Then run `./check-setup.pl` script again and it will create the tables again. You could save the users table and add the users back once the script is done to avoid having to create all of the users again if you have many.